# try to install ethcracker

Tags: go-ethereum

Installing on windows 10.

- did install chocolatey
- did choco install git
- did choco install golang
- did choco install mingw

Now i need to install go language as specific in the docs by using

```
git clone https:/github.com/lexansoft/ethcracker
?? command git not recognised
```

Also next steps fail

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> go get github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum: exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

Who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Chocolatey

Chocolatey installs in seconds. You are just a few steps from running choco right now!

First, ensure that you are using an administrative shell - you can
    also install as a non-admin, check out Non-Administrative

Open The Path : `C:\Windows\System32` search `cmd.exe` 
and Mauser right button click and

> Run as administrator and this command run

[image]

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

Try it

Thanks You!